# How to animate TextView

Tags: android-layout, android-animation, textview, android

I have a custom class extending `TextView` (I used this trick to set my custom font).
I've a `ListView` and its elements are represented with my custom `TextView`.
Sometimes happens that the text is too long to fit and it starts a new line. I want to avoid this, so i set `android:singleLine=true` in the `XML` of my element layout.

I want to know if it's possible to animate the `TextView` of an element of the list, so that if such element is selected, it first scrolls its text to the left, till it reaches the end of the text, then scroll back to the right till the beginning.

I tried with marquee but it looks like it can only move in one direction and it's not what i want.

Comment: check API demos in android SDK